how to remove the underline in a MudNavLink
I'm using the MudNavLink component with fontawesome and it looks a bit messy with an underline so I want to remove it.  Ive tried this


<MudNavLink Href="Account/Register" Style="text-decoration:none"  Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix" Icon="fa-solid fa-registered">Register</MudNavLink>
<MudNavLink Href="Account/Login" Style="text-decoration:none" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix" Icon="fa-solid fa-right-to-bracket">Login</MudNavLink>



but it makes no difference, anyone know how this can be done ?


Just the icon? Add a > i {text-decoration:none;} to the CSS and see if that helps. You can later be more specific about with i elements in links get removed, like specifying font-awesome classes

MudBlazor doesn't underline nav links by default, do you have some other site css being applied?

Doh !  I was checking out Microsoft FluentUi and had this line in my App.razor file


<link href="_content/Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components/css/reboot.css" rel="stylesheet" />



removing it solved the problem
